# traceId and spanId are coming as same throughout the loggers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

Using a Spring boot with below gradle dependency to get the Sleuth's trace & span, although I am getting trace & span id's in my logs but they both are same, like even in controller & service class they are same.

gradle.build :

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.4.RELEASE')
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.1.4.RELEASE'
```

logback.xml:

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level  trace=%X{X-B3-TraceId} span=%X{X-B3-SpanId} MSG=%m%n"/>
```

Aspect class :

```
@Around("execution(*  com.test.common.controller.*.*(..))")
public Object controllerAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (requestAttributes == null) {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    myLoggingServices(joinPoint, requestAttributes, httpServletRequest, startTime);
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

console logs :

```
2021-07-16 13:41:56.008 [qtp1043203786-34] INFO   trace=474376a508632a04 span=474376a508632a04 qualifiedClass=com.test.common.controller.MyController time=14

2021-07-16 13:41:56.009 [qtp1043203786-34] INFO   trace=474376a508632a04 span=474376a508632a04 qualifiedClass=com.test.common.controller.MyController time=1

2021-07-16 13:41:56.291 [qtp1043203786-34] INFO   trace=474376a508632a04 span=474376a508632a04 qualifiedClass=com.test.common.service.impl.MyServiceImpl time=0

2021-07-16 13:41:56.292 [qtp1043203786-34] INFO   trace=474376a508632a04 span=474376a508632a04 qualifiedClass=com.test.common.service.impl.MyServiceImpl time=0
```

Is there anything missing that I should add, please see that Spring boot version is fixed due to app dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing nothing as this reflects the behavior you get by the default instrumentation by Spring Cloud Sleuth. Once you open your own span within a trace, you will see that the span ID will be different:

```
@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;

[...]

Span span = this.tracer.nextSpan().name("customSpan");
try (Tracer.SpanInScope ws = this.tracer.withSpan(span.start())) {
    [...]
    log.info("Should log custom span");
    [...]
}
finally {
    span.end();
}
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, where should this code is, any specific type of class and "Span" in you code is using which library. Also is this a difference in behaviour in sleuth & brave, bcoz in another maven I didn't had to do that.

Comment: This is not any specific configuration. You use the above code wherever you want to open a new span. Please review the [Span lifecycle section in the Spring Cloud Sleuth documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#span-lifecycle).

Comment: I tried doing the same as you suggested but seems to be giving me the same result (traceid=spanId)

Comment: import brave.Span;
import brave.Tracer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class CustomisedSpan {

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomisedSpan.class);

    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

    public void customSpan() throws Throwable {
        Span span = this.tracer.nextSpan().name("customSpan");
        try (Tracer.SpanInScope ws = this.tracer.withSpanInScope(span.start())) {
            logger.info("Should log custom span");
        } finally {
            span.finish();
        }
    }
}

Comment: You should definitely get a different span ID once you open your own custom span. For example, if you add the above sample code to any handler method of a web controller, you should see a different span ID when you call the handler method.

Comment: sir can you clarify what you meant by Handler, I tried few things but didn't work out. Any specific type of class it should be. "Tracer.nextSpan()" should create child span but not able to implement in successfully.

Comment: Please take a look at the following code that embeds my example code from above in a `RestController`: https://pastebin.com/Fnm1gHMz